# Component for carousel in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, carousel

I make some app for Android/IOS in Visual Studio with Xamarin (not Xamarin.Forms). There are ViewFlipper in Android designer, which I use for carousel component. Is there any same in IOS? I mean not 3-rd party component, but native like ViewFlipper in Android.

Comment: Use a `UIStackView` with `CATransition` for pushing/flipping/sliding the UIViews on and off... :  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks for suggestion but UIStackView needs IOS 9.0, and my app needs support for 8.0

Comment: iOS 8.0, thats old, less than 2% if the market... without going w/ an existing 3rd party lib, and v8, I would just use multiple UIViews and CATransition on an embedded UIViewController...

Comment: @SushiHangover unfortunately customer doesn't care about "iOS 8.0 is old". =) Thanks for idea about UIViews set. I think it is possible to use set of UIImageViews (one is visible other hidden) inside UIView as container.

Answer (score -1):

you can use 100% IOS & Android Api with Xamarin, means what ever is Available in android or IOS you can use in Xamarin.

there no built in carousel component in IOS.

I am using [Syncfusion Carousel](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin/carousel) and it is free.